# Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'String' - Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting an error currently in terms of date picker and gesture control. I am not entirely sure how to fix this but I think it is something in relation with Strings. I would appreciate if someone could have a look and help me out. Thanks!

```
private var daysDifference = 0

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
let todayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date.init())
self.userDate.text = todayDate


@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
                
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
                  print("Swipe Right")
                 view.backgroundColor = .black
                 self.daysDifference = self.daysDifference - 1 // Update daysDifference for one day before
           } else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
                  print("Swipe Left")
                  view.backgroundColor = .yellow
                  self.daysDifference = self.daysDifference + 1 // Update daysDifference for one day after
           }
        
        self.userDate.text = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: self.daysDifference, to: datePicker!.date)! // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'String'
        
       }
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a Date (the result of `Calendar.current.date`) to `text`, which is a `String`. The answer will depend on what format you want. Search "Swift Date to String" on SO or Google and you'll find many possibilities.

Comment: So you have a DateFormatter, why not use it again when updating userDate.text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you are trying to set the text of a label/text field (which is of type `String`) to a `Date`. Those types are not interchangeable.

You need to convert your `Date` to a `String`.

Change this line:

```
self.userDate.text = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: self.daysDifference, to: datePicker!.date)! // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'String'
```

To this:

```
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: self.daysDifference, to: datePicker!.date)!
self.userDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from:newDate)
```